# Merging a small image on a big image

Tags: php, gd

I have a small image with dimensions 190W and 40H. I need to merge/place this image on a big image with dimensions 650W and 148H. I tried many things but none of them work. Currently I am using the code

### Big Image

[image]

### Small Image

[image]

```
$png = imagecreatefrompng('images/bigimage.png');

$jpeg = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/smallimage.jpg');

list($width, $height) = getimagesize('images/smallimage.jpg');

list($newwidth, $newheight) = getimagesize('images/bigimage.png');

$out = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

imagecopyresampled($out, $jpeg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

imagecopyresampled($out, $png, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $newwidth, $newheight);

imagejpeg($out, 'images/saved.png');
```

This is producing the result which I needed. But the problem is that the small image is pixelated on the large image like

The output I am getting is like this where the small image is pix-elated. Please someone help me to make this perfect.

[image]

Comment: Try converting the `jpg to png` or the `png to jpg`, maybe it's because they arent the same format

Comment: Thanks. But these are in the same format. I have cross checked.

Comment: Maybe a typo, but   imagecopyresampled($out, $jpeg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height); stretches the small image to the full size of the target image.

Comment: Yes I found this. At that point I am totally confused and don't know what to do.

Comment: Can I make a perfect output without the line  imagecopyresampled($out, $jpeg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height); or is there any other solution?

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve this.?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution like. Hope this will be helpful for someone.

```
$png = imagecreatefrompng('images/bigimage.png');

$jpeg = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/smallimage.jpg');

list($width, $height) = getimagesize('images/smallimage.jpg');

list($newwidth, $newheight) = getimagesize('images/bigimage.png');

$out = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

$jpeg_canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

imagecopyresampled($jpeg_canvas, $jpeg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
//imagejpeg($out, 'images/saved.jpg'); exit;
imagecopyresampled($out, $png, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($out, $jpeg_canvas, 135, 15, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($out, 'images/saved.jpg');
```